# Help learning Yemenite teamim for Yom Kippur morning Haftorah

Tags: trop-cantillation, yemenite-temani

How can I best learn the Yemenite teamim so I can chant the Yom Kippur morning Haftorah?  I am already fluent with Ashkenazi teamim.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us

Comment: I made some edits to your question - hopefully to make it easier to answer - feel free to revert or [edit] further